# Function not working if called inside the IF and the While Loop

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm currently working on iMacro + Javascript that operates like this:

1. Open a website. *(i have a function openwebsites(); which contains tons of website urls)*.
2. Check the web page if the "follow button" exist
3. [Loop] If it doesn't exist, do Number 1 again (Open a website). This will repeat until it finds a website with a "follow button"
4. If the button Follow exist, mouse over to different positions displayall(); within the page.

my problems are this:
A. I've used the While Loop which i'm not sure if this is the best approach. BTW, I'm just a beginner user of javascript.
B. the code displayall(); is not functioning, nothing happens if it finds a website with follow button.

Below are imacro+javascript code.

```
var followbutton

followbutton ="CODE:";

followbutton +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
followbutton +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

iimPlay(followbutton)

var text=iimGetLastExtract();

while (text.search("Follow")!=0) {
    openwebsites();
    if (text.search("Follow")!=1) { 
        displayall();
        break;          
    } 
}


function displayall() {

var displayall;
displayall ="CODE:";

displayall +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";
displayall +="TAG POS=10 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";
displayall +="TAG POS=15 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";

iimPlay(displayall)

}
```

Comment: The line `displayall();` is never reached, you break the loop before.

Comment: so I should put the break; after the displayall():?

Comment: Isn't that obvious?

Comment: still the same result. nothing happens. i tried it.

Comment: Then we need to see the code for `displayall` function ...

Comment: does `iimGetLastExtract` return a **string**?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it did.

Comment: THe only way the code could not run an infinite loop is if text does not begin with `Follow` but has `Follow` in it - if `text` is anything without `Follow`, then the while condition is always true, and the if condition is always false - because `text` can not change

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your loop as shown below, it will work. The below code, has an infinite while loop which will run openwebsites() function first, then check for Follow Button and then if present run displayall() function, else it will run from the beginning again.

***Note:*** This loop will continue running, if you can provide openwebsites() code with some sample pages, a normal while loop can be created to loop through the number of websites, since there is not enough information to work with I have chosen an infinite loop.

```
var followbutton

followbutton ="CODE:";

followbutton +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
followbutton +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

do {
    openwebsites();
    iimPlay(followbutton);
    var text=iimGetLastExtract();
    if (text === 'Follow') { 
        displayall();  
    } 
}while (true);


function displayall() {

var displayall;
displayall ="CODE:";

displayall +="TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";
displayall +="TAG POS=10 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";
displayall +="TAG POS=15 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";

iimPlay(displayall)

}
```